# CSS: attach a button with perfect height alignment to input

Tags: html, css

Let's assume for a second I **do not wish to use Bootstrap**.
How do you achieve his perfect vertical alignment of the input with its button? When I do it the button vertically misaligns. I do not wish to use "hacking" on the top-margin to fix this as I'm afraid it won't look well on all browsers.

How is bootstrap achieving this magic?

my goal is something like this:

[image]

Comment: What about `vertical-align`?

Comment: Can you show us the code that's not working for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer would be using `box-sizing: border-box`, as bootstrap does. This works across all recent modern browsers:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Your text here">
<button>Button</button>
```

```
input{
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
button{
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4dgzbc3y/

Comment: Perfect, `box-sizing` fixed an issue when I had elements aligned in Chrome, but off by one pixel on Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use a container and display both as table cells ([working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/32acqmr7/15/)):

Markup:

```
<div class="container">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Your text here">
    <div class="button">
        <a>Button</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
    display:inline-table;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
input{
    display:table-cell;
    padding:5px;
}
.button{
    display:table-cell;
    background:gray;
    padding:5px;
}
```

Note:
Keep in mind general things like both having the same font size and padding. To make it look slick you can round the outer corners same as in bootstrap :)

Comment: Doesn't look perfectly aligned in recent Firefox, Chrome or Safari.

Comment: @mmgross Or...IE11. =( gutter ball'd.

Comment: I'm working on an IE11 fix, latest chrome and ff are working as expected on my machine.

Comment: Screenshot of how it looks for me on Chrome as of now (v15): https://www.dropbox.com/s/m45rsl4nwxxpwr1/Screenshot%202015-04-07%2003.04.12.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Have an input and button with explicit heights. The `input` and the `button` will need a comment between them to "connect" otherwise they will have na ugly space

```css
.target {
  height: 2em;
}

.target * {
  height: 100%;
  display:inline-block;
  border:none;
  outline:none;
}

.target input {
  width:79%;
  background-color:black;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.target button {
  width:10%;
  background-color: orange;
  box-sizing: margin-box;
  padding: 0; margin: 0;
  border-top: 2px orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="target">
  <input placeholder="Foo" type="text"><!--
  --><button>Bar</button>
</div>
```